# view results of SAS operations in the Output window

Tags: sas

I switched from `SAS` to `R` years ago.  However, someone recently gave me a `SAS` file I hope to translate to `R`.  I have discovered `SAS` has changed so much over the years that I cannot even figure out how to display the results of a `print` statement.

Here is a simple `SAS` file:

```
data a;
   input group x;
   cards;
1 12
1 14
1 16
2 11
2 13
2 15
;

proc print;
  var group x;
run;
```

If I copy and paste the above code into `SAS 9.4` on a Windows desktop nothing appears in the `Log` window, nothing appears in the `Output` window and nothing appears in the `Results` window.

By the way, I have clicked the `Create Listings` option under: `Tools> Options> Preferences> Results>`

I suspect the current version of `SAS` requires that I provide some sort of code in addition to checking the box next to `Create Listings` before `SAS` will display results in the `Output` window, but I do not know what that line of code must be.

How can I view the results in the `Output` window like I used to do with `SAS` years ago?  Thank you for any advice.  I cannot imagine a more basic question and apologize if this is a duplicate.

Comment: run the following in a new SAS session and see if you get any output. If you do, try adding the explicit data=a to your print and/or odd listing on; command. proc means data=sashelp.class; run;

Comment: @Reese Thank you for the suggestion.  If I run `proc means data=sashelp.class; run;` I do not get any output. I also tried running `command. proc means data=sashelp.class; run;` and got no output.

Comment: @Reese I just remembered that with `SAS` I cannot run code by simply pasting it into the `Editor` window.  I also have to click the `Run>Submit` command.  With `R` I can run code by simply pasting it into the `GUI`.  When I click the `Run>Submit` command then my `SAS` code runs.  I feel a little silly, but it has been approximately seven years since I used `SAS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly telling SAS to use the listing Window.

```
ods listing;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAS Enterprise Guide you need to run your code via F8, this will then display your results in the results page